# Getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 5) while trying to calculate KNN score

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to calculate the score for my model selection algorithm for KNN and while trying to compute f1_score, I am getting the error. Here is my code:

```
def print_report(y_actual, y_pred, thresh):

    auc = roc_auc_score(y_actual, y_pred)                     #Calculates Area Under Curve (AUC) score.
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_actual, (y_pred > thresh))    #Calculates total accuracy of model.
    recall = recall_score(y_actual, (y_pred > thresh))        #Calculates recall score.
    precision = precision_score(y_actual, (y_pred > thresh))  #Calculates precision score.
    specificity = calc_specificity(y_actual, y_pred, thresh)  #Calls functions where specificity is calculated.
    f1 = f1_score(y_actual, (y_pred > thresh))                #Calculates f1_score.
    print('AUC:%.3f'%auc)
    print('accuracy:%.3f'%accuracy)
    print('recall:%.3f'%recall)
    print('precision:%.3f'%precision)
    print('specificity:%.3f'%specificity)
    print('prevalence:%.3f'%calc_prevalence(y_actual))
    print('f1 score:%.3f'%f1)
    print(' ')
    return auc, accuracy, recall, precision, specificity, f1
```

and the next part:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 120)
knn.fit(X_train_tf, y_train)

y_train_preds = knn.predict_proba(X_train_tf)[:,1]
y_valid_preds = knn.predict_proba(X_valid_tf)[:,1]

print('KNN')
print('Training:')
knn_train_auc, knn_train_accuracy, knn_train_recall, \
    knn_train_precision, knn_train_specificity, knn_train_f1 = print_report(y_train,y_train_preds, thresh)
print('Validation:')
knn_valid_auc, knn_valid_accuracy, knn_valid_recall, \
    knn_valid_precision, knn_valid_specificity, knn_train_f1 = print_report(y_valid,y_valid_preds, thresh)
```

Error occurs here:

```
knn_train_precision, knn_train_specificity, knn_train_f1 = print_report(y_train,y_train_preds, thresh)
```

I am only able to calculate the score for my training dataset, not validation. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please post the exact error and the line it occurs on.

Comment: @Kalpit please check the edit now